# How to do switching between two diffrent swich statements using C?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I have written a c code for switching between two different switch statements,
but I am looking for a more generic solution, meaning without using state variable and while loop, or jump from one switch statement to another switch statement.
I want some suggestion or key input from you.

Thank you and please excuse my poor English.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{   
    unsigned char state,state1;
    enum
    {
        Add,Sub,Mul,Div,START,STOP
    }Arith_Op;

    enum
    {
        Add1,Sub1,Mul1,Div1,START1,STOP1
    }Arith_Op1;

    Arith_Op = Add;
        Arith_Op1 = Add1;
    state = START;
    while (state != STOP) 
    {
        switch(Arith_Op)
        {
            case Add :
                printf("Add\n");
                Arith_Op = Sub;
            break;

            case Sub :
                printf("sub\n");
                Arith_Op = Mul;
            break;

            case Mul :
                printf("mul\n");
                Arith_Op = Div;
            break;

            case Div :
                printf("div\n");
                Arith_Op = STOP;
            break;

            default :
                printf("default\n");
                state = STOP;
                state1 = START1;
            break;  
        }
    }
    printf(" state out of while and Switch case ");



    while (state1 != STOP1) 
    {
        switch(Arith_Op1)
        {
            case Add1 :
                printf("Add1\n");
                Arith_Op1 = Sub1;
            break;

            case Sub1 :
                printf("sub1\n");
                Arith_Op1 = Mul1;
            break;

            case Mul1 :
                printf("mul1\n");
                Arith_Op1 = Div;
            break;

            case Div1 :
                printf("div1\n");
                Arith_Op1 = STOP1;
            break;

            default :
                printf("default1\n");
                state1 = STOP1;
            break;  
        }
    }
    printf(" state 1 out of while and Switch case ");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible in c, but why don't you use some kind of array, key-value pair or map? Like string operation=operations_array[add];

Comment: Remember to set `state1 = START1;` even when you don't hit your default case in the first switch.

Comment: I can't think of any much better way to write your code. A loop around a switch is pretty normal for this task and experienced C programmers around you would likely approve.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you _actually_ trying to do? What is the final purpose of your program? Tell us more. Elaborate your question.

Comment: is this is only way to get out from while loop ? using flag ????

Comment: end application may be anything I just want conditional switching between while loop and switch statement .

Comment: You could use a goto to jump out, but literally no one would find it more stylistically pleasing.

Comment: `break` can get one out of a while loop, however with a switch nested in a while loop, that will not work.  Instead, one could use a `goto` to break out of nested loops/switches.  It will make Structured Programming acolytes have a heart attack, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Several comments have indicated that your question is unclear. Please try to give more information. " I just want conditional switching between while loop and switch statement." was not different enough from the phrasing in the question to give anybody any more idea about what you want to achieve. Consider giving more information about the goal you want to achieve by doing this. Repeating what you think is the next step has not helped the readers. That is what one of the comment indicates by referring to the XY Problem. Please read up on that, it really seems to be the core problem here.